# Unable to download msnodesql-0.2.1-v0.10-x64.msi

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-reporting

I'm trying to write Node.js code to connect to Azure SQL Database and unable to install the "msnodesql" module for my node.js application, it through's an error saying that " Unable to download msnodesql-0.2.1-v0.10-x64.msi". so can any one please look into this and help me out... below is the screen shot of error msg..[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using Node version 0.10.36 while, according to the [package github page](https://github.com/Azure/node-sqlserver), this package is only supported in node 0.8.9.

Make sure you have the following prerequisites satisfied:

1. Use a node version 0.8.x
2. Python 2.7
3. Visual C++ 2010 Express

All of this is information is available [here](https://github.com/Azure/node-sqlserver).

Comment: You may also want to look into Tedious as an alternative driver. This will work with the most recent version of node. Learn more about Tedious here: https://github.com/pekim/tedious

Comment: To add to what Eli said, if you wish to still use the msnodesql driver with node.js version 0.8.x, please follow the documentation here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-nodejs-simple-windows/
This have been tried and tested and it will allow you to exploit some of the ODBC driver capabilities that Tedious does not have. If you have any more questions please let us know :)